# How to do a batch STDistance using a Table Type with Lat Longs?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, geospatial, spatial

I am trying to pass a Table Type into a stored procedure and would like the sproc to look up each row of lat/longs and return to me the nearest point for that row.

Type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.LatLongRoadLinkType AS TABLE
( 
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Latitude FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Longitude FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

Stored Proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BatchNearestRoadNodes]
    @Input dbo.LatLongRoadLinkType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- do stuff here
    -- return a table of id from input, nodeid and distance 
END
```

It needs to do for the whole table what is done here for a single lat/long:

```
DECLARE @g geography = 'POINT(13.5333414077759 54.549524307251)';
DECLARE @region geography = @g.STBuffer(5000)

SELECT TOP 1 NodeID, Point.STDistance(@g) as 'Distance'
FROM Location 
WHERE Point.Filter(@region) = 1
ORDER BY Point.STDistance(@g)
```

The Location table has the important column Point of type Geography, which is spatially indexed and is what the comparisons are done against.I am sending the table of lat/longs from code into the sproc, and the code is expecting a return of :

```
Id (original point passed in)
NodeID (of nearest point in location table)
Distance
```

How should I approach this? To perhaps make it a bit easier I could simply pass in a SqlGeography from my code into the sproc instead of Lat/Long, however that would kill the performance since its very expensive to convert to that.

**EDIT:
This works, don't know if its the most optimal solution however.**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BatchNearestRoadNodes]
    @Input dbo.LatLongRoadLinkType READONLY
AS
BEGIN

SELECT x.Id, x.LocationName, x.NodeID, x.Distance
FROM (SELECT I.Id,
        L.LocationName,
        L.NodeId,
        L.Point.STDistance(geography::Point(I.Latitude, I.Longitude, 4326)) AS Distance,
        ROW_NUMBER ()  OVER (PARTITION BY I.Id ORDER BY L.Point.STDistance(geography::Point(I.Latitude, I.Longitude, 4326)) ASC) AS Ranking
        FROM @Input AS I
        JOIN Location AS L 
        ON L.Point.STIntersects(geography::Point(I.Latitude, I.Longitude, 4326).STBuffer(5000)) = 1
    ) AS x WHERE Ranking = 1
END
```

**Performance - V1 vs Jon's Edit**

```
V1
============
original:643 found:627 in:1361 ms
original:1018 found:999 in:1700 ms
original:1801 found:1758 in:2628 ms
original:4098 found:3973 in:5271 ms
original:16388 found:15948 in:19624 ms

Jon's Edit
==========
original:643 found:627 in:1333 ms
original:1018 found:999 in:1689 ms
original:1801 found:1758 in:2559 ms
original:4098 found:3973 in:5114 ms
original:16388 found:15948 in:19054 ms
```

The difference is minimal. Need to get the last figure down.

Comment: You're going to have to convert to SqlGeography at some point at any rate if you want to take advantage of a spatial index.  Whether you pass it as float/float and then convert it or just pass it as SqlGeography you've got to convert it.  Unless you have massive numbers in your table the overhead isn't all that bad.  Which version of SQL are you running?

Comment: @Muhammed.  Looks good, and glad mine gave some basis.  The only thing I'd say is that you're converting the geography twice in the query.  Consider using a subquery / CTE as I did to first calculate the geography instances once and then re-use it.  What times are you getting with what number of rows?

Comment: No problem, all done.  I actually liked your ROWNUMBER()... solution.  For some reason I hadn't considered it but it's effective.  Answer updated below.  Hope it works this time and geography is only converted once, not three times.  Will save a few ms.  Let me know how it improves.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to get partial results:

```
WITH PreQuery AS
(
I.Id,
GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText(I.PointAsWKT).STBuffer(5000) AS Geog,
L.NodeId,
L.Point
FROM
@Input AS I
JOIN
Location AS L ON L.Point.STIntersects(I.Geog) = 1
)
SELECT
P.Id,
P.NodeId,
P.Geog.STDistance(P.Point) AS Distance
FROM
PreQuery P
```

I've written it from off the head and without any test data so there may be small bugs but in the main it will give you every node and it's distance (within 5000 metres) from every point.  You'll still need to filter them to get only the one with the minimum distance for each id - shouldn't be too hard ;-)

Hope it helps somewhat, even if not complete.

**EDIT (2nd Dec)**

I already see the problem with my first solution, you can't get the distance because it's pre-buffered (to note the main thing).  However, this amalgamation should be the most efficient combination of both attempts.

```
WITH PreQuery AS
(
SELECT
I.Id,
geography::Point(I.Latitude, I.Longitude, 4326) AS InputGeography
FROM
@input AS I
)
SELECT x.Id, x.LocationName, x.NodeId, x.Distance
FROM
(
SELECT
PQ.Id,
L.LocationName,
L.NodeId,
L.Point.STDistance(PQ.InputGeography) AS Distance,
ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.Id ORDER BY L.Point.Distance(PQ.InputGeography) ASC) AS Ranking
FROM
Prequery AS PQ
JOIN
Location AS L
-- ON L.Point.STIntersects(PQ.InputGeography.STBuffer(5000)) = 1 -- Slower
ON L.Point.STDistance(PQ.InputGeography) <= 5000 -- Faster
) AS X WHERE Ranking = 1
```

This way, you pre-create the input geography only once, not three times as per your attempt.  Again this is untested but should prove the most efficient.

Comment: Hi Jon, please see performance results in my edit. Trying to find a way to improve accuracy and speed. Maybe a recursive approach would work, ie, with small buffer, then bigger and bigger with lower amount of points.

Comment: I'm not convinced a recursive would work, as you've got to deal with multiple calls and filtering at each level.  Try altering the join to `L.Point.STDistance(PQ.InputGeography) <= 5000`.  Have you also checked the query plan to make sure the spatial index is being used?

Comment: Yes that has improved things, now the last one is 14475 ms :) I will edit your answer to add V3.